# Unable to use new SATA 3TB drive in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: partitioning, sata

I bought a new Seagate 3TB SATA-II HD. I installed it in the computer myself. The `Disks` program in Ubuntu recognizes the HD. When I try to create a partition table in Disks, I get this error:

```
Error creating partition table: helper exited with exit code 1: Error calling fsync(2) on /dev/sdb: Input/output error
```

Here is the output of `fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0005dd31

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     9764863     4881408   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         9766910   976771071   483502081    5  Extended
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5         9766912   107421695    48827392   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       107423744   974817279   433696768   83  Linux
/dev/sda7       974819328   976771071      975872   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdc: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xc27c4f8f

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1            2048   625137344   312567648+   c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)

Disk /dev/sdb: 3000.6 GB, 3000592982016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 364801 cylinders, total 5860533168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/sdb doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

I have tried gparted but it fails as well. Any help? Could this be a SATA data cable issue?

Comment: Check `dmesg` for more detailed errors and the SMART stats in the disk utility.

Comment: Did you try to `delete` the existing partition table first then try to `Create a new partition table on unallocated space` using `Gparted`. Reply..

Comment: If we keep some questions open that turned out to be hardware problems and have answers saying that (like this one), then people with similar situations that are really hardware problems will be more likely to get answers and less likely to post their own hardware problems as new questions. This didn't just *go away*; the problem was discovered and fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be a SATA Cable issue.